# BAT file terminates itself when activating a kivy script

Tags: python, batch-file, kivy

I'm running my own app which uses Kivy on Python on Windows. Every time I use the app I needed to activate the kivy venv script before running the app, which I found cumbersome so I created a batch file to go along with it:

```
@echo off
python -m virtualenv kivy_venv 
kivy_venv\Scripts\activate
python myapp.py
pause
```

The problem is, the batch file terminates itself right after kivy_venv\Scripts\activate, and I am pretty sure these are the lines I typed in the command prompt to get it working anyway, so what went wrong there?

E: I'm seeing comments to use `call` before the activate line but it seems to yield the same problem so I suspect there might be an issue with Kivy's activate.bat file itself:

```
@echo off

set "VIRTUAL_ENV=C:\......\kivy_venv"

if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT (
    set "PROMPT=%_OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT%"
) else (
    if not defined PROMPT (
        set "PROMPT=$P$G"
    )
    if not defined VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT (
        set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT=%PROMPT%"
    )
)
if not defined VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT (
    set "ENV_PROMPT="
    if NOT DEFINED ENV_PROMPT (
        for %%d in ("%VIRTUAL_ENV%") do set "ENV_PROMPT=(%%~nxd) "
    )
    set "PROMPT=%ENV_PROMPT%%PROMPT%"
)

REM Don't use () to avoid problems with them in %PATH%
if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME goto ENDIFVHOME
    set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME=%PYTHONHOME%"
:ENDIFVHOME

set PYTHONHOME=

REM if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH (
if not defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH goto ENDIFVPATH1
    set "PATH=%_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH%"
:ENDIFVPATH1
REM ) else (
if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH goto ENDIFVPATH2
    set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH=%PATH%"
:ENDIFVPATH2

set "PATH=%VIRTUAL_ENV%\Scripts;%PATH%"
```

Comment: This has been covered many times before throughout the [[tag:python]] [[tag:batch-file]] tagged pages of this site. Use `call kivy_venv\Scripts\activate`, instead of `kivy_venv\Scripts\activate`.

Comment: I tried that, but it still yielded the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what's causing the problem: apparently I've been calling the wrong `kivy_venv` this whole time.

So I have a `kivy_venv` in my app folder, but I also found out that there is another `kivy_venv` folder in C:\Users<myusername> as well, so I switched to calling that and voila, it worked! Turns out that is the venv my app has been using all along!

Changed

```
kivy_venv\Scripts\activate
```

to

```
call C:\Users\<myusername>\kivy_venv\Scripts\activate
```

Thanks to everyone who helped but in hindsight I really should have seen this myself!